# cmake can't find Python3 but found version 3.8

Tags: python, cmake

Error using cmake, does not recongnize `python3`, but also says (found version "3.8").

I have Python 3.8.5 located in:

```
python3.8: /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3.8 /etc/python3.8 /usr/local/lib/python3.8 /usr/include/python3.8 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.8.1.gz
```

and also Python 2.7.18 in

```
python2: /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/lib/python2.7 /etc/python2.7 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/share/man/man1/python2.1.gz
```

I also have the python development package updated (3.8.5-1~20.04).
I'm using cmake version 3.16.3

The error is this one:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:146 (message):
  Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Interpreter) (found version "3.8")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:393 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython/Support.cmake:2214 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/FindPython3.cmake:300 (include)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:72 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/dani/ALE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/dani/ALE/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The error line in src/CMakeLists.txt is:

*find_package(Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)*

Comment: Hey, I'd suggest amending the headline as the issue you have is not a function of the business internal options you're passing. Maybe to something like "cmake can't find Python3 but found version 3.8"
Can you also show the `find_package(Python3...)` part of your cmake code - i.e. around line 72 in the src/CmakeLists.txt? And what cmake version are you using and which python3 versions are available on your system, and where? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Firmament, I have just edited it!

Comment: Do you really need the Development dirs? I guess it finds a 3.8 with only the dirs but not the interpreter and then fails instead of searching on for a version that has both the interpreter and the directories? If you need both then setting the Python3_FIND_STRATEGY might be an option?